# pyqt widget not expanding to parent

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

trying to get a custom widget to expand to parent and it's only doing what I want when my widgets are inheriting from QLabel instead of QWidget. I have tried setting QSizePolicy but it still doesn't seem to be working

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from mywidgets import MenuLabel, MenuWidget, MainWidget


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("InstaPlus")
        outerlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        outerlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        outerlayout.setSpacing(0)

        menulayout = QVBoxLayout()
        menulayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        menulayout.setSpacing(0)

        menuwidget = MenuWidget()
        mainwidget = MainWidget()

        menulayout.addWidget(MenuLabel("Menu Item 1"))
        menulayout.addWidget(MenuLabel("Menu Item 2"))
        menulayout.addWidget(MenuLabel("Menu Item 3"))
        menulayout.addWidget(MenuLabel("Menu Item 4"))
        menulayout.addWidget(MenuLabel("Menu Item 5"))
        menulayout.addStretch()
        menuwidget.setLayout(menulayout)

        outerlayout.addWidget(menuwidget)
        outerlayout.addWidget(mainwidget)

        self.setLayout(outerlayout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.resize(800, 500)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is my mywidgets code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QSizePolicy


class MenuLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = title
        self.setText(self.title)
        self.setStyleSheet(open("styles.css").read())


class MenuWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAccessibleName("menu")
        self.setStyleSheet(open("styles.css").read())
        self.setFixedWidth(200)


class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAccessibleName("main")
        self.setStyleSheet(open("styles.css").read())
```

Here is the layout when inheriting from QWidget

[image: QWidget]

and this is it when my widgets are inheriting from QLabel

[image: QLabel]

How can I get my widgets to inherit from Qwidget and and have them resize like a QLabel?

Here is the styles file

```
MenuLabel{
    background-color: #484848;
    color: #dadada;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Geneva', 'Verdana', sans-serif
}

MenuLabel:hover{
    background-color: rgba(8, 3, 9, 0.65);
    }

[accessibleName="menu"]{
    background-color: #484848;
}

[accessibleName="main"]{
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

Comment: share the styles.css

Comment: indentation improved

Comment: what are *my widgets*?

Comment: What do I have to change to get the second image?

Comment: first picture is when custom widgets are inheriting from QWidget ie.. 
Class MenuWidget(QWidget): 

Second photo is inheriting from QLabel ie... 
Class MenuWidget(QLabel):

I would like these widgets to inherit from QWidget but expand to match size of parent.

also styles.css has now been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of your `MenuWidget` class is exactly the same whenever you subclass from QWidget or QLabel.

The problem is that when subclassing from QWidget it's not enough to set the stylesheet. As the official [stylesheet reference documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) explains:

> If you subclass from QWidget, **you need to provide a paintEvent** for your custom QWidget.

```
class MenuWidget(QWidget):
    # ...
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, qp, self)
```

If you're using `accessibleName()` just as a stylesheet selector, do consider that it's not a good choice, as the accessible name can (should) be *localized* and is not the right method to identify a class in stylesheets. Use the `objectName()` instead, and the `#objectName {}` selector instead. See the [selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) chapter in the stylesheet syntax documentation.

Comment: @JamesSmith Note that if you only need to have a background color, there are also other alternatives: just use `qp.fillRect(self.rect(), color)` instead of creating a QStyleOption, use container class that supports styling (like QFrame, which is coincidentally is the same class QLabel inherits from), or set the palette with a specific `Window` role color on the container widget and ensure to call `setAutoFillBackground(True)` if it's not already set for the class.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It is only the background colour that I'm after so think I will just inherit from QFrame instead. I have also now changed my styling to use objectName instead of accessibleName.